# Function not returning in javascript

Tags: javascript

EDIT: MADE A NEW FUNCTION WITH IF... still doesnt return -.-. I dont understand why.

I am trying to return results of calculating the taxes, total and total + taxes in this function. I want the results to be printed in h3 like the following:

```js
 function taxesrepas(option){
var soustot;
var taxes;
var total;
var soustot;



if (option = getelementbyid("spaghetti")) 
    total += 9.62;
    taxes += 0.67;
    soustot +=8.95;

if (option = getelementbyid("lasagne"))
    total += 10.70;
    taxes += 0.75;
    soustot += 9.95;

if (option = getelementbyid("salade"))
    total +=  6.30;  
    taxes += 0.45;
    soustot += 5.95;
if (option =getelementbyid("escargot"))
    total += 5.32;
    taxes += 0.37;
    soustot += 4.95;




 
    document.getElementById("taxes").innerHTML = taxes;
    document.getElementbyid("total").innerHTML = total;
    document.getElementbyid("soustot").innerHTML = soustot;
        
  }
```

```html
<h3 id="choix"></h3>
<h3 id="taxes" onclick= "taxesrepas(this.value)">taxes:</h3>
<h3 id="soustotal" onclick= "taxesrepas(this.value)">Sous-total:</h3>
<h3 id="total"onclick= "taxesrepas(this.value)">Total:</h3>
```

This function is the function that is supposed to calculate the different prices from the users choice on the select menu. The problem is it will not return anything for some reason. I want the results to print in these h3.

This is an example of what I want it to look like. As the select menu changes, taxes and prices change.
[URL=https://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=204967Capturedecran20170930a121531.png][IMG]https://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/204967Capturedecran20170930a121531.png[/IMG][/URL]

Comment: <h3> does not have/use a value property, nor do they trigger onchange events

Comment: what do you think that `this.value` is in your code? Or better, what do you want it to be?

Comment: I am trying to return the prices from the if statements, I used this.value because it is a number. Im really new to this im not quite sure how to fix my function -.-, right now I see I am missing {} and correcting that rn

Comment: `I am trying to return the prices from the if statements` why? you don't use the returned value from the function anyway. And, Even if the function is right, the way you call it is malicious. That's why I asked about `this.value`; because there is no property `value` on `this` in the context you use that. `h3` nodes have no `value`. And btw. the version of your function with the `switch` in it didn't look that bad, but you need to provide a little bit more context *(html markup)* where this code should work in.

Answer (score 1):

The `value` property is only available on user input elements, not `<h3>`. And the `change` event is only triggered when you change the value of an input element, it doesn't apply to `<h3>`.

You can use `textContent` to get the string in an `<h3>` element. And if you want the action to happen when you click on it, use `onclick`. So they should be like this:

```
<h3 id="taxes" onclick="taxesrepas(this.textContent)">taxes:</h3>
```

Also, in the function, you should move the calculations that use `taxer` and `pricer` to *after* the `switch` statement that sets those variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use `h3` tags like they are input tags.

the `onchange` event only fires for form elements like `<input>`, `<textarea>`, or `<select>`. Similarly, an `<h3>` does nat have a `value`, because that is also a property of form elements.

Comment: I made a new function but im still having problem returning the value into the h3 tags. Anyone can help me with this ?

Comment: Please update your question to include your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onChange` from your h2 tags as they don't have **onchange** events.
Put a button instead and use `onclick()` to call your function,  get your h1 values by using `getElementById(id)` in your function.

```
<button onclick="taxesrepas()">
```

Other way, I see you are trying to get option value.

Use `select` instead and check the values in your switch case.