# Javascript not returning results from my function

Tags: javascript

I made a similar post but didn't get my answer or my code working, so I decided to go with a switch function to an if function and this is it!

```
function taxesrepas(option){
    var soustot;
    var taxes;
    var total;
    var soustot;

    if (option = getelementbyid("spaghetti")) 
        total += 9.62;
        taxes += 0.67;
        soustot +=8.95;

    if (option = getelementbyid("lasagne"))
        total += 10.70;
        taxes += 0.75;
        soustot += 9.95;

    if (option = getelementbyid("salade"))
        total +=  6.30;  
        taxes += 0.45;
        soustot += 5.95;
    if (option =getelementbyid("escargot"))
        total += 5.32;
        taxes += 0.37;
        soustot += 4.95;

        document.getElementById("taxes").innerHTML = taxes;
        document.getElementbyid("total").innerHTML = total;
        document.getElementbyid("soustot").innerHTML = soustot;
      }
```

The function is to return the price of taxes and the totals, from a select menu. 
This is where I want my results to be printed but they just don't print, I've tried with the switch now with if I'm literally going crazy.

```
<h3 id="choix"></h3>
<h3 id="taxes" onclick= "taxesrepas(this.value)">taxes:</h3>
<h3 id="soustotal" onclick= "taxesrepas(this.value)">Sous-total:</h3>
<h3 id="total"onclick= "taxesrepas(this.value)">Total:</h3>
```

Comment: I can't see `return` statement in your function ..? Also, `if` is not a function, it's a statement.

Comment: That is not how `if`s work. You need to add curly braces `{}` in this case. And there is a difference betwen `=` and `==`.

Comment: Also all the `if` statements should have `==` instead of `=`

Comment: Your variables are **undefined**!

Comment: I sure hope you like spaghetti

Comment: alsoo the condition is not right you have the element's value in "option" but you are comparing it to the element itself rather than its value

Comment: The code in the post would actually need an error comment almost on every line ... `getelementbyid` is not a native method, `option` is probably not an element ..? + all the above mentioned details ... Huh!

Comment: I suggest you properly learn JavaScript.. This looks like translated Python code

Comment: That is what im trying to do matheus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function not returning in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504676/function-not-returning-in-javascript)

Comment: i have defined my variables... can someone show me the right way ? im so lost

Comment: @bourki You declared the variables, for example: `var soustot` but the definition is missing. Example: `soustot = "foo"`. As suggested, you should study up on the basics of JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: looks more like http://coffeescript.org than JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of syntax errors in your code. I suggest you browse the web for basic tutorials.

> 1. You are not initializing your variables:

```
var taxes;
var total;
var soustot;
```

calling `total += 9.62` is an error because `undefined` plus a number is `NaN`

> 2. You are using `=` assignment instead of `==` comparison in you if conditions

should be `if(somevariable == somevalue)` not `if(somevariable = somevalue)`

> 3. You are not enclosing your if statements with curly braces `{}`

```
if(somevariable == somevalue)
   dosomething1(); // your if statement only includes up to this part
   dosomething2(); // this line does not belong to the if statement
```

you should:

```
if(somevariable == somevalue) { //opening here
   dosomething1();
   dosomething2();
} //closing here
```

> 4. What the heck is `getelementbyid("spaghetti")`. Where have you defined a function named `getelementbyid`?
> 5. It's `document.getElementById` not `document.getElementByid` (*you have used small* <kbd>i</kbd>)
> 6. You are treating your `<h3>` elements like buttons when you wanted those elements to change when you have selected an option, correct?
>
>    - you are adding `onclick` attribute. This should be `onClick`
>    - you are passing `this.value` to your function. You should do `this.innerHTML` instead

***HOWEVER,*** I strongly discourage you to do something like that.

if you want to add listeners to specific elements, do it in JavaScript. Yes, adding `onClick` inline events are valid, but it requires you to put JS behaviours to your HTML. One more reason is that writing events in your JS makes it a lot maintainable.

You can try:

`document.getElementById('total').onClick = somefunction`

Anyway, here's the least I could come up with.

supposedly you have a `<select>` that contains your options and then when selecting an option, you see the price. *(then spaghetti spurts in your nose)*.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('optioncombo');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  taxesrepas(select.value);
});

function taxesrepas(option) {
  //you need to assign a starting value for your variables or you will get NaN when using +=
  var soustot = 0,
    taxes = 0,
    total = 0,
    soustot = 0;

  //getelementbyid is not a function!!!
  //if (option == getelementbyid("spaghetti")) {
  if (option == "spaghetti") {
    total += 9.62;
    taxes += 0.67;
    soustot += 8.95;
  }
  if (option == "lasagne") {
    total += 10.70;
    taxes += 0.75;
    soustot += 9.95;
  }

  if (option == "salade") {
    total += 6.30;
    taxes += 0.45;
    soustot += 5.95;
  }
  if (option == "escargot") {
    total += 5.32;
    taxes += 0.37;
    soustot += 4.95;
  }

  document.getElementById("choix").innerHTML = option;
  document.getElementById("taxes").innerHTML = taxes;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
  document.getElementById("soustotal").innerHTML = soustot;

}
```

```html
<label for="optioncombo">Product: </label><select id="optioncombo">
  <option value="none"></option>
  <option value="spaghetti">spaghetti</option>
  <option value="lasagne">lasagne</option>
  <option value="salade">salade</option>
  <option value="escargot">escargot</option>
</select>

<h3>Your choice is:</h3><span id="choix"></span>
<h3>taxes:</h3><span id="taxes"></span>
<h3>Sous-total:</h3><span id="soustotal"></span>
<h3>Total:</h3><span id="total"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I assume, that you want to make some calculations based on a selection of dish options. You had multiple severe errors in your code and should definitely study how to code in JavaScript. Here are some mistakes, you made:

- You need to take care about case sensitivity: `getelementbyid` is not the same as `getElementById`.
- A function which is an attribute of another variable is not the same as a global function: `document.getElementById` ≠ `getElementById`
- Omitting the curly braces after an `if` statement is dangerous. It will always only affect the upcoming line. Always use curly braces in an if statement. In your case, only the first calculation was made. (`if(...) { ... }`)
- `<h3>` elements do not have a `value`, only input and radio boxes do have a `value`. Therefore, you cannot pass this "option" as an argument.
- You tried to bind the value of e.g. Taxes as an option to a function which then evaluates, if it is a dish (Spaghetti etc.). This cannot work like this.
- `+=` is only necessary, if you want to add a number to an existing number. Otherwise, you can simply use `=`
- You cannot compare anything by using `=`. This operator is for assigning variables. You need to use `==` or better `===`.
- If you only declare a variable (e.g. using `var soustot;`) and not initialize it (setting a value to it), its value will be `undefined`. You cannot add a number to `undefined`. It will result in a `NaN` value (not a number).
- The term of returning values from a function is specifically used, if you want to get some output directly as a return value inside JavaScript. You actually want to set some DOM values and not return a value to the caller of the function. For example `Math.round(1.643);` returns `2` but does not set any DOM properties.

Nevertheless, here you have a working example:

```js
function taxesrepas() {
  var soustot = 0;
  var taxes = 0;
  var total = 0;
  var soustot = 0;
  var selectedOption = document.selectionForm.selectionOption.value;

  if (selectedOption === 'spaghetti') { 
     total = 9.62;
     taxes = 0.67;
     soustot = 8.95;
  } else if (selectedOption === 'lasagne') {
     total = 10.70;
     taxes = 0.75;
     soustot = 9.95;
  } else if (selectedOption === 'salade') {
     total =  6.30;  
     taxes = 0.45;
     soustot = 5.95;
  } else if (selectedOption === 'escargot') {
     total = 5.32;
     taxes = 0.37;
     soustot = 4.95;
  }

  document.getElementById("taxes").innerHTML = taxes;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
  document.getElementById("soustot").innerHTML = soustot;
}
```

```css
label { display: block; }
```

```html
<div>
  Taxes: <span id="taxes"></span>
</div>
<div>
  Total: <span id="total"></span>
</div>
<div>
  Soustot: <span id="soustot"></span>
</div>

<hr>

<form name="selectionForm">
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="selectionOption" value="spaghetti">
  Spaghetti
</label>
<label> 
  <input type="radio" name="selectionOption" value="lasagne">
  Lasagne
</label>
<label> 
  <input type="radio" name="selectionOption" value="salade">
  Salade
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="selectionOption" value="escargot">
  Escargot
</label>
</form>

<button onclick="taxesrepas();">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback everyone. I will be working on my code and I will post back my final answer. You definately have helped a lot, and I know I can only improve from this point in javascript.. :)